# Making a CSS footer either sit at the bottom of the browser window or bottom of content

Tags: css

**Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page).**

I've got an existing site ([jacquelinewhite.co.uk](http://www.jacquelinewhite.co.uk)), on it there is a footer. Currently this footer always sits underneath the main content. I'm trying to make it float to the bottom of the browser window, or if the content is bigger than the window, stay at the bottom of the content.

Effectively the HTML is structured like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="top_bar">
  </div>
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="left_menu">
</div>
<div id="right_content">
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<!-- FOOTER AREA -->
<div id="footer">
</div>
<!-- END FOOTER AREA -->
</div>
```

I have tried absolute position, bottom 0, which puts the footer at the bottom of the window, but if the content of the window is bigger then the footer covers the content.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This one's always worked well for me: [CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: Sadly, the link is now dead.

Answer (score 4):

Test drive this...

```
  body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:0;
  }

  #toolbar {
    background:#ddd;
    border-top:solid 1px #666;
    bottom:0;
    height:15px;
    padding:5px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1000;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's not quite what I'm after, I'd like the footer to flow with the content, rather than always site at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using footer() element I found just adding this to CSS worked for me

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```