# Footer overlapping content on low res canvas

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with a footer I can't make stick to the bottom of the page. It's probably just a line I forgot, I've done this multiple times in the past, so I'm sure it's just a silly mistake. I've cleaned up the page so it's easier for you to tell me what I'm forgetting. It works fine when content doesn't pass it, remove some `<br />`s in the content code and you'll see it does the job of staying at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/MS4KJ/

```
#footer{
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#aaa;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    height: 100px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't want it to be sticky.

Comment: so this is correct. Why are you using too much <br/>. When you will place the contents then no need to place the <br/>.

Comment: look at this tread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616290/making-a-css-footer-either-sit-at-the-bottom-of-the-browser-window-or-bottom-of

Comment: Oh, I know, I only did that to simulate loads of content on this blank page.

Comment: @freshbm I don't want a sticky, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
position: relative;
```

or if you want sticky footer look at this tread: [Making a CSS footer either sit at the bottom of the browser window or bottom of content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616290/making-a-css-footer-either-sit-at-the-bottom-of-the-browser-window-or-bottom-of)

and this site: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Edit:

Try set body padding to 0px and footer margin to 0px and also remove footer left: 0px.
That sholud remove white spaces around footer. 
Take look at this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I get now that the position has to be relative. What I can't do is make it full width when I set it to that, I always get part of the canvas to the left, bottom and right when I do that.

Comment: Try set body padding to 0px

Comment: Thanks. It was actually the margin:0 that was missing in body that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
#footer{
    position: relative; 
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#aaa;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    height: 100px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Else, select the maximum height and give a `min-height` for the `#content`.

```
#content {min-height: 350px;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do I have blank spaces between the footer and the canvas' borders now?

Comment: You didn't want it to be sticky right, then this is the only way.

Comment: What you mean is I can't get rid of these (http://i.imgur.com/JRstQNv.png) white spaces if I use a relative position?

Comment: Oh the whitespaces on the top huh? Dude, easy... Give a `margin-top: -10px`.

Comment: Not really, on the left and right and bottom. Although if I do `margin:-10px;` it fixes all but the right margin.

Comment: Do this: `margin: -10px 0;`

Comment: Fixes bottom, makes left and right still have the space.

Comment: Remove that zero. Make `margin: -10px`.

Comment: Like I said, it fixes all but the right margin. `margin-right:-10px;` also does nothing.

Comment: Give adding more width. Say, kinda `width: 110%`?

Comment: See this is fixed in teh fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MS4KJ/1/

Comment: Try set body padding to 0px and footer margin to 0px and also remove footer left: 0px

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I'm pretty sure that would make my page scroll. Anyway, freshbm's margin:0 fix worked. Thanks for all the help, though. And for fixing my OP.